# How to use OpenGL on top of SSH?

Tags: linux, opengl, x11, ubuntu-18.04, bulletphysics

I am trying to use `PyBullet` on a remote computer. The remote computer has an NVIDIA RTX 2070 GPU card with 410 drivers. `xlogo` works fine.

A quick test gives me the error:

```
>>> import pybullet as p; p.connect(p.GUI);
pybullet build time: May 13 2019 09:52:59
startThreads creating 1 threads.
starting thread 0
started thread 0 
argc=2
argv[0] = --unused
argv[1] = --start_demo_name=Physics Server
ExampleBrowserThreadFunc started
X11 functions dynamically loaded using dlopen/dlsym OK!
X11 functions dynamically loaded using dlopen/dlsym OK!
Creating context
Failed to create GL 3.3 context ... using old-style GLX context
Failed to create an OpenGL context
```

I can get such error using `glxgears`:

```
$ glxgears
  X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  151 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  31
  Current serial number in output stream:  32
```

To debug it, I tried to do :

```
$ ldd `which glxgears`
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffce6fad000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007fc9a9ecc000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fc9a9b2e000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fc9a97f6000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc9a9405000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007fc9a91d4000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007fc9a8f1e000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc9a8cff000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc9aa35e000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fc9a8ad7000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fc9a88d3000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fc9a86cf000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fc9a84c9000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007fc9a82b4000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fc9a80ac000)
```

Apparently, `nvidia` is not employed here:

```
$ ll /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL*                                    
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   22 mai   10 14:17 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so -> libGLdispatch.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   22 mai   10 14:17 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 -> libGLdispatch.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 599K mai   10 14:17 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   29 juin  18 12:27 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.1 -> libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.410.48
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  59K juin  18 12:27 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.410.48
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 mai   10 14:17 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM.so -> libGLESv1_CM.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 mai   10 14:17 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM.so.1 -> libGLESv1_CM.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  43K mai   10 14:17 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 juin  18 12:27 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2 -> libGLESv2_nvidia.so.410.48
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 109K juin  18 12:27 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.410.48
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   18 mai   10 14:17 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2.so -> libGLESv2.so.2.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   18 mai   10 14:17 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2.so.2 -> libGLESv2.so.2.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  71K mai   10 14:17 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2.so.2.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 août  24  2017 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so -> libGLEW.so.2.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 août  24  2017 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.2.0 -> libGLEW.so.2.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 575K août  24  2017 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.2.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  671 juin  18 12:27 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   14 mai   10 14:17 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so -> libGL.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   14 mai   10 14:17 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 555K mai   10 14:17 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 905K mai   22  2016 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 mai   22  2016 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so -> libGLU.so.1.3.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 juin  14  2018 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1 -> libGLU.so.1.3.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 443K mai   22  2016 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   44 juin  18 12:42 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.0.so -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   23 juin  18 12:27 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_indirect.so.0 -> libGLX_nvidia.so.410.48
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 févr.  8 23:02 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0 -> libGLX_mesa.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 469K févr.  8 23:02 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   23 juin  18 12:27 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.0 -> libGLX_nvidia.so.410.48
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1,3M juin  18 12:27 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.410.48
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 juin  18 12:48 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 -> libGLX.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67K mai   10 14:17 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 mai   10 14:17 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0.bak -> libGLX.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 mai   10 14:17 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.bak -> libGLX.so.0.0.0
```

I tried to install `libglvnd`, to reinstall nvidia, but it did not change anything.

I am a kind of lost here. I don't really know what I should investigate to go further.

Comment: When you say that xlogo works fine do you mean it's displayed locally or on the remote machine?

Comment: I meant that I launch it on the remote machine through `ssh` and it displays correctly on my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think much can be done here. Core X11 ( via GLX extension in "INDIRECT" mode ) only support relatively old subset of OpenGL. Most modern opengl drivers work in "direct" mode: you communicate to X server using DRI extension to allocate some video memory / screen region to you, and then render to that video memory directly using GPU, completely bypassing network layer.

Depending on your opengl driver and on the program ( in must be able to fall back to inderect mode ) you might have some luck by setting `LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT` variable to 1

Comment: Ok too bad I was hoping that libglvnd could replace GLX (https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/915640/multiple-glx-client-libraries-in-the-nvidia-linux-driver-installer-package/). When I do `export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1`, `ldd` reports the same stacks. I don't understand why it does not use `libGLX_indirect`

Comment: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/915640/multiple-glx-client-libraries-in-the-nvidia-linux-driver-installer-package/

Comment: I wonder also if I could use VirtualGL here, but it goes outside of my skills